# Rails Devise-JWT capture generated tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, jwt

I'm using https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt to generate authentication tokens for my users.  The gem doesn't store the tokens in the database, instead it generates a signed token on the fly. Without the token expiring or the user revoking the tokens, I have no way of knowing which tokens are out there and live at a given moment.

I wonder if it is possible to store the generated tokens in the database upon creation in a simple way so that a user, or an admin can revoke a token at a later point in time.

I currently set the time limit of a token to be around 5 minutes, so my exposure wouldn't be too long, but that said, I would like to know what tokens are live at any one time.

Thanks.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt#jtimatcher

Comment: Not really.  Using that method, only a single client can log in at a time.  Custom strategy is perhaps required here.